# Backlit, silent, mac compatible keyboard

Tags: keyboards, silent

I've been programming with corsair k55 RGB keyboard and I absolutely love it!
It is not noisy at all, the feeling of typing is great and I love the fact that it is lighted.
The only problem is that I am using a Macbook and I am missing the macro buttons (not supported).

I am looking for backlit, mac compatible, silent keyboard with macro buttons.
Around 50$ would be great.
I really like Logitech but it is too expensive for me.